# Highcharts axis break is not collapsing section

Tags: highcharts

Adding a break to a highcharts x-axis is still causing the full gap to be shown instead of collapsing the section to shift the points closer together as the API and example there shows. The gap is actually smaller when the break is removed in the below example, but not in my actual use case.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/25pf0nve/1/

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

         xAxis: {
           breaks: [{
             from: '20170131',
             to: '20180101',
             breakSize: 0
           }]
        }, 

        series: [{
           color: 'red',
           name: '01',
           // data from 20170101 to 20170131
           data: [[1483228800000, 75.78125], [1484524800000, 50.120483], [1485820800000, 20.049505]],
           id: 0
        }, {
            color: 'red',
           name: '01',
           // data from 20180101 to 20180131
           data: [[1514764800000, 94.73684], [1516060800000, 95.89977], [1517356800000, 37.5]],
           linkedTo: 0
        }]
    });
```

Expected gap to be non-existent, so the 20170131 data point would be adjacent to the 20180101 data point. Instead, the gap was large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify `break.from` and `break.to` according to the xAxis type. Here the xAxis have `type: datetime` so the break should be like this:

```
xAxis: {
  breaks: [{
    from: 1485820800000, // 20170131
    to: 1514764800000, // 20180101
    breakSize: 0
  }]
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uspqeto0/)